# javascript fill combobox with ajax but in C# selected value is null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, combobox

I have some issue with filling a combobox with javascript.

```
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = 'HOLA MUNDO';
optn.value = '2';
ComboBoxName.options.add(optn);
```

That is filled with ajax because its combo who are filled depending of another combo.

But in c# when i need to use

```
ComboBoxName.SelectedItem.Text
```

the SelectedItem is null

Somebody know about that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're inserting an option into a select element on the client side and then you check for the value on the server side. Server side has no idea what's going on on the client side. Unlike input elements, select (or the combo as you say) is not meant for editing, but as the name implies, it's for selecting only. So the server code is only aware of the dropdownlist items that were added on the server side. That's why no matter how many options you push to that select element the server will reject to recognize them. Things left to do

1. You either select only the original options (those that present since the server response)
2. Or you go AJAX

BTW, by default ASP.NET will not accept a dropdownlist (which is rendered as a select element) that has been changed since the last response. This is for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for response

Indeed all what you said its rigth. 

To handle this i adding two hidding fields.

When the button who call the server is firing, the JavaScript set the values in the hidden fields with onClientClick method.

And the server recognize these values.

But i wonder if there some problem with security thing.

Thanks very much

Comment: Let's make this clear. We use select elements to: 1. Limit choises to certain values 2. Avoid misspelling 3.(Although not necessarily) Present numeric values in user friendly form, like 1:BMW,2:Mercedes,3:Ford etc. Now assume, you insert value in the hidden field to a database and you've set a foreign key constraint and someone opens html inspector and edits the hidden field to a value that will violate the constraint and sends it to the server, what will happen? While I don't claim that it's a 100% security hole, it still can be depending on the situation.